# Navigation graph scoped ViewModel on Process Death

Tags: java, android, viewmodel

While I am trying to handle Process Death in my Android Application, I noticed that the ViewModel which was scoped to the navigation Graph was crashing while recreating from the process death. Below is the code of the ViewModel and the Fragment which is using the ViewModel.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltViewModel
class ViewPrintOrderVM @Inject constructor(
private val repository: Repository,
private val application: Application,
private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

     // Code inside the ViewModel

}
```

And in my Fragment, I am getting the reference as follows

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ComposeFragmentPostPressDetails : Fragment() {

        //Here we are scoping the ViewModel to the Navigation graph with graph-id instead of this fragment
        private val viewModel: ManagePrintOrderVM by navGraphViewModels(R.id.print_order_flow)

       //Rest of the Fragment code

}
```

Now, when I try to test the app for process death by launching the app in the emulator, putting it in the background, and then killing the process with the "Terminate Application" button from the android studio, it crashes while recreating with the following error

```
2022-03-19 19:06:44.633 7174-7174/com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow, PID: 7174
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow/com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.ManagePrintOrderVM
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.ManagePrintOrderVM
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.FragmentPaperDetails.getViewModel(FragmentPaperDetails.kt:42)
        at com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.FragmentPaperDetails.observeViewModel(FragmentPaperDetails.kt:97)
        at com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.FragmentPaperDetails.onViewCreated(FragmentPaperDetails.kt:59)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.sivakasi.papco.jobflow.screens.manageprintorder.ManagePrintOrderVM> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

However, all other screens where the ViewModel is scoped just to that Fragment instead of scoping it to the navigation graph are working fine on Process recreation even with dependency injection.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to handle Process death in a flow? How to handle process recreation in the fragments where the ViewModel is scoped to the Navigation Graph instead of the fragment itself or the Activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`by navGraphViewModels` knows nothing about your Hilt factory - it is just using the default factory. The only reason it may work in other cases is because another fragment that *did* use Hilt's factory had created the ViewModel first.

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodel-navigation), you must use `by hiltNavGraphViewModels()` to use a Hilt injected ViewModel scoped to a navigation graph.

```
// Add this to your dependencies
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'

// Then use it in place of navGraphViewModels()
private val viewModel: ManagePrintOrderVM by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.print_order_flow)
```

Comment: I am already using the ```by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_transaction_graph)```
and when i kill the process and open the app i am getting destination cannot be found. any idea on what i might be doing wrong? @ianhanniballake

Comment: @hushed_voice did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Viewed Yeah.. I had 2 nav graphs and I was selecting the graph according to a condition on login. when kill the process, it was defaulting to a different graph than the intended one.

Comment: I am using graph with kotlin dsl, then I don't have the graph id, then how?
I am using but its not working and it should not be workable ```private val navViewModel: SharedNavViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(findNavController().graph.id)```

Comment: @Kawsar - you'd have to [file an issue against Hilt](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=874079&template=1438695) if you'd like them to support `navGraphViewModels` with a `route` - it appears they only support the Kotlin DSL when using Compose.